# Perl Script calling Subroutines within Subroutines?

Tags: perl, formatting, output

Hi So I created the following script for outputing to a wiki page. The problem is that I am not sure in how to format my output. Here is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
#use warnings;
my $TOTALIOS = 'totalios';
my $READP = 'readpe';
my $CACHEP = 'cachehit';
my $CKBSEC = 'currentkb';
my $MKBSEC = 'maximumkb';
my $CIOSEC = 'currentio';
my $MIOSEC = 'maxio';
my $DATESTORE = 'dates.sec';
my $DATECMD = strftime "%m/%d/%y", localtime;
my $TIOS = 'Tios';
my $READp = 'readp';
my $CACHEp = 'cachep';
my $CKBsec = 'ckbsec';
my $MKBsec = 'mkbsec';
my $CIOsec = 'ciosec';
my $MIOsec = 'miosec';
my ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR) = &mysubinput;
sub mysubinput
{
    print "Enter the number for the datastore: \n";
        my $STORENUM = <STDIN>;
        chomp($STORENUM);
        print "Enter the name for the datastore e.g: DataStore or ServerStore: \n";
        my $STORENAME = <STDIN>;
        chomp($STORENAME);
        print "Enter the data store image prefix e.g. datastore or serverstore: \n";
        my $IMGPREFIX = <STDIN>;
        chomp($IMGPREFIX);
        print "Enter the month MM: \n";
        my $MONTH = <STDIN>;
        chomp($MONTH);
        print "Enter the day DD: \n";
        my $DAY = <STDIN>;
        chomp($DAY);
        print "Enter the Year YYYY: \n";
        my $YEAR = <STDIN>;
        chomp($YEAR);
    return ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR);
#   print "$STORENUM $STORENAME $IMGPREFIX $MONTH $DAY $YEAR\n";
#   print "Not a very interesting routine\n";
#   print "This does the same thing every time\n";
#   print "$TOTALIOS\n";
#   print "Enter the number for the datastore: \n";
#   $line = <STDIN>;
#   chomp($line);
#   print "$line\n";
#   print "$DATECMD\n";
}
sub writedate 
{
    print "! $DATECMD\n";   
}    

sub writesections(mysubinput())
{

    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$TIOS-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$READp-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$CACHEp-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$CKBsec-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$MKBsec-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$CIOsec-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:$STORENAME-$STORENUM-$MIOsec-$MONTH-$DAY-$YEAR.png| 100px]]\n";
}   

sub writepage
{
    &mysubinput;
    print "Go back to [[MD3000i-Perf]] \n";
    print "{| border=1 cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 style=text-align: center \n";
    print "|-\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-1]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-2]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-3]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-4]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-5]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-6]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-7]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-8]]\n";
    print "! [[DataStore-9]]\n";
    print "|-\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "| [[File:disk.png |60px]]\n";
    print "|}\n";
    print "{| border=1 cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 style=text-align: center\n";
    print "|-\n";
    &writedate;
    print " |-\n";
    &writesections;
    print " |-}\n";
}
#&mysubinput;
&writepage;
#&mysubinput;
#&writesections;
```

Using this approach things seem to work. However, my input is not 100% right. I have to input all my data twice, before the program can spit somthing ....

```
Enter the number for the datastore:
1
Enter the name for the datastore e.g: DataStore or ServerStore:
DataStore
Enter the data store image prefix e.g. datastore or serverstore:
datastore
Enter the month MM:
12
Enter the day DD:
03
Enter the Year YYYY:
2012
Enter the number for the datastore:
1
Enter the name for the datastore e.g: DataStore or ServerStore:
DataStore
Enter the data store image prefix e.g. datastore or serverstore:
datastore
Enter the month MM:
12
Enter the day DD:
03
Enter the Year YYYY:
2012
Go back to [[MD3000i-Perf]]
{| border=1 cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 style=text-align: center
|-
! [[DataStore-1]]
! [[DataStore-2]]
! [[DataStore-3]]
! [[DataStore-4]]
! [[DataStore-5]]
! [[DataStore-6]]
! [[DataStore-7]]
! [[DataStore-8]]
! [[DataStore-9]]
|-
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
| [[File:disk.png |60px]]
|}
{| border=1 cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 style=text-align: center
|-
! 12/04/12
        |-
| [[File:DataStore-1-Tios-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-readp-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-cachep-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-ckbsec-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-mkbsec-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-ciosec-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:DataStore-1-miosec-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]
        |-}
```

Things seem to work now after adding this variable to 'my'

```
my ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR) = &mysubinput;
```

second piece was to add 
    return ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR);

Now my questions is how do i get the output from sub writesections into a file, such as datastore.wk?

Comment: Why have you commented out `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: sorry i miss that... using warnings i do get:                       Global symbol "$STORENAME" requires explicit package name at ./testperl.pl line 61.
Global symbol "$STORENUM" requires explicit package name at ./testperl.pl line 61.
Global symbol "$MONTH" requires explicit package name at ./testperl.pl line 61.
Global symbol "$DAY" requires explicit package name at ./testperl.pl line 61.

Comment: @user1814718 Those are errors you should fix. That's what strict and warnings does, tells you what errors you have in your code. Just declare those variables using `my` in the scope that is appropriate for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not ever comment the `use strict` line :)

It would alert you that your `writesections` sub doesn't have the access to the variables declared inside the scope of `mysubinput`!

I suggest you to learn about [private variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) first. To share your variables, you should `return` them. Following your logic:

```
sub mysubinput
{
    ...
    return ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR);
}

my ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR) = mysubinput();
writesections($STORENAME, $STORENUM, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR);
```

However, if you expect to grow your Perl script, sooner or later you'll have to learn Object-Oriented Programming. Then, [Moose framework](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html#Moose) is your friend.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `&writesections` subroutine calls. It has been bad practice for eighteen years now.

Comment: ... or `writesections(mysubinput())` :)

Comment: thanks guys ok so using `code` &writesections i get the output but its not clean i have to input my data twice: my $MIOsec = 'miosec';
my ($STORENUM, $STORENAME, $IMGPREFIX, $MONTH, $DAY, $YEAR) = &mysubinput;

Comment: OK everything works i got it! thanks how can i output the sub writepage to a file? I like to use the output of this sub to import it into another site?

Comment: @user1814718 you could `open($output, ">", "output.txt"); select $output;` to redirect all `print`s to the file. But you'll need to restore the normal output with `select \*STDOUT`, then. It would be preferred to `print $out "Enter...";` explicitly.

Comment: now following where would i put open($output, ">", "output.txt"); select $output; would this go in the "sub writepage" what about the select \*STD....

Answer (score 2):

If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` enabled you would see messages like

```
Global symbol "$STORENAME" requires explicit package name
```

which are there to help you debug your program.

The problem is that the variables you have declared within `mysubinput` are *local* to that subroutine and will be discarded when the subroutine returns. As far as `writesections` is concerned these variables have never been declared, and the program won't compile.

Uncomment those `use` statements, and add declarations for `$DAY`, `$MONTH`, `$STORENAME`, `$STORENUM`, and `$YEAR` before the first subroutine that uses them, and remove the `my` from those variables within the subroutines. Then they will be accessible throughout the rest of the file and your program should work.

By the way, calling subroutines with `&mysubinput` is a very old style indeed. You should use `mysubinput()` throughout.

Comment: Great so to add the declarations i would do something like $DAY = ""; just after my $MIOsec = 'miosec';